# unit-test build fails on itself in VS

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I have a simple MVC 3 website. When I open the solution I have no problem running the test. However if I try to run it the 2nd time or modify a test line and run again I get the error

> Error  12  Unable to copy file "...\MvcMobile\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll" to "bin\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll' because it is being used by another process.    MvcMobile

I don't have any instance open. What is with this? All I am doing is running test and every test has completely ran (3 functions all 2 lines long)

Comment: How do you have SQLLite.Interop.dll referenced? Is it in the GAC? Can you see if Copy Local is set to true or false for that assembly, and maybe try switching it?

Comment: @rsbarro: It's set to true. When I put false it was able to build but both test and website got a runtime error on load saying it can't load the reference which is weird because it should still be in the folder. I tried copying the x86 to bin root and still no go